# Ng2-table not working with latest Angular2 version

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently using Angular2 for my application and now I want to add ng2-table to my component. 
[ng2-Table on Git](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table)

I am getting this error and couldn't help but ask:

```
 angular2-polyfills.js:487 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'colums' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-table'.
    1. If 'ng-table' is an Angular component and it has 'colums' input, then
    verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ng-table' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA"
    to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
     ("
    </div>-->
    <ng-table [ERROR ->][colums]="columns" [rows]="rows" > </ng-table>
    <div class="">
    "): DeviceOverviewComponent@18:10 ;
    Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…)
```

In my html I got this:

```
<ng-table [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows" > </ng-table>
```

My Component is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { DeviceService } from '../services/device.service';


@Component({
   selector: 'device-overview',
   templateUrl: 'dist/html/deviceoverview.component.html',
   providers: [DeviceService],

})
export class DeviceOverviewComponent {
   devices: any;
   columns: any;
   rows: any;
   constructor(private deviceService: DeviceService, private router: Router) {
   }

   loadDevices() {
      this.deviceService.getDevices()
         .then((data) => {
            this.devices = data
            this.rows = this.devices
         })
   }

   goToDevice(deviceName: string) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/devices/' + deviceName)
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.columns = [
         { title: "test", name: "id" }]
      this.loadDevices();
   }

}
```

And my app.module is this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';
import { DeviceOverviewComponent } from './components/deviceoverview.component'

import { DeviceService } from './services/device.service';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      Ng2TableModule,
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      routing,

   ],
   declarations: [
      DeviceOverviewComponent,
      AppComponent,
   ],
   providers:
   [
      {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
      DeviceService,

   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Does anybody know anything about the Usage of ng2-table? Or is there a valid alternative, since the demo page/usage documentation is not available by now?

I found some alternatives, but lots of them had their last commit a long time ago, which might be a problem, since I am always using latest Angular2.

Thanks for reading and any hel is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I've made it to the next step!

I needed to add

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core'
@NgModule({ ...,
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
```

within my app.module.ts

Now I am getting the table header with the "test" column and the ID property of my row data is displayed correctly.

Even the demo from ng2-table didn't have that import. 
I guess docs and demos arent made for newbes nowadays. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see a typo in your html:

```
[colums]="columns"
```

It should be

```
[columns]="columns"
```

You're missing `n`

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4cakPQS2RkaLQHzGHFUA?p=preview)** (I also tried it on local machine and it works)

**You shouldn't use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA**

**systemjs.config.js**

```
map: {
  ...
  'ng2-table': 'npm:ng2-table'
},
packages: {
  ...
  'ng2-table': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

Comment: Whups, yes. But thats only a typo in my question. Ill fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`. Remove it. What is the error do you see after that?

Comment: Removing it gets me back to the starting point of my question. Why shouldn't I use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA? Also your Plunker doesn't work for me.

Comment: Original error says `If 'ng-table' is an Angular component and it has 'colums' input`. You shouldn't to use `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` because `ng-table` isn't a Web Component. It is a Angular component

Comment: So the "verifying" part is to add that to the system.js.config? I thought I only needed to put it into my module imports. Well, thank you!

Comment: yes, you have to import it in your module. Try also print `console.log(Ng2TableModule)`

Answer (score 0):

After long time I close this issue.

In my case I have these structure:

```js
src
--app
  -- app.module
  -- TravelPlan
    -- travel-plan.module
    -- test.component
```

So, I was trying put the ng2-smart-table in app.module, but I was wrong. The correct is put in travel-plan.module.